# EF Core custom extension query, The LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

how can i do something like that?

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> CustomWhere<TEntity>(this
            IQueryable<TEntity> entities,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> getProperty,
        bool isTrue)
    {
        return isTrue ? entities : entities.Where(getProperty);
    }
}


var users = (
from user in _context.Users

let userChange = _context.UsersChange.CustomWhere(e => e.RegisterName == request.RegisterName,
string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RegisterName)).FirstOrDefault()

select new
{
    test = userChange
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

now i have error "The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation EF Core 3.1"

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. This error is happening because the expression you are trying to use cannot be used because there is no way to translate it to a database command to run directly. This is why it's telling you to switch to client evaluation. If you google your error there are a lot of results for the issue. If you look at those and apply the same to your issue you may be able to get around the problem. Also it is useful to create a minimal verifiable example for posting on SO - this can help you figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Custom extension methods can *only* be used with *top level* queryables, since that's the only case when they are actually executed. When used inside query expression tree (as in your example), the "call" is just recorded, but never called, and during the translation they are treated like any unknown method.

Hence the solution is to move the call (of course when possible) to a top level query variable, and then use the variable inside the actual query, e.g.

```cs
var userChanges = _context.UsersChange
    .CustomWhere(e => e.RegisterName == request.RegisterName,
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RegisterName));
// Note that the above just defines a query without executing it
// Now it can be used inside the main query
var users = (
    from user in _context.Users
    let userChange = userChanges.FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        test = userChange
    }
);
```